# Error showing a list of data in a UITableView w/ AZ sections

Tags: swift, uitableview, dictionary

The idea of this app is to show in a TableView a list of selected countries (divided by sections -az-), but when I run the app it gives an error:

[image]

And, when I change "sorted" to "sort" it gives another error:

[image]

**Idk why these errors appear. Anyone can help me please?**

These are the lines of code I wrote:

```
var countryListS = ["A": ["Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan"], "B":["Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi"]]

struct Objects {
    var countryName : String!
    var countryObjects : [String]!
}

var objectArray = [Objects]()

@IBOutlet var listCountriesTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    listCountriesTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellCountry")
    let sortedCountries = sorted(countryListS) { $0.0 < $1.0 }
    for (key, value) in sortedCountries {
        print("\(key) -> \(value)")
        objectArray.append(Objects(countryName: key, countryObjects: value))
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to resolve the `sort` error, update the following code in your `viewDidLoad` method.

```
for (key, value) in countryListS {
    let sortedCountries = value.sort(<)
    print("\(key) -> \(sortedCountries)")
    objectArray.append(Objects(countryName: key, countryObjects: sortedCountries))
}
```

Comment: awesome! it works... but it looks in disorder (n..f...a...z...m... etc,etc) How can i solve that? thanks

Comment: store the keys of your dictionary as a separate **titles** array and sort it. Use the sorted array for your section titles. To populate rows in section, get the values based the title value for that section.

Comment: If you want all the alphabets to be displayed, then create an array of alphabets [A-Z] and use it for your section titles.

Comment: If this answer helped you resolve the issue, you could mark this as answered!!